# Multiple Series in Line chart in Winform using C#

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, data-visualization

I am new in `Winform Application`. I am trying to implement a `line chart` which have  multiple `series` and have a `checkedListbox` to select the `particular series`.

**Code:**

```
if (tbROI.SelectedTab == tbROI.TabPages["tbPageROIPoint"])
            {
                //If all ROI TAB
                myIndex = GetMyChartIndex(mSeries, chartPointROI); // 4 for Point ROI tab

                m_PointDataCounter++;
                if (m_PointDataCounter > 15)
                {
                    if (myIndex > 5)
                    {
                        chartPointROI.Series[mSeries].Points.RemoveAt(0);
                        m_PointDataCounter--;
                    }
                }

                if (cbListPOI.GetItemChecked(ROIIndex))
                {
                    chartPointROI.Series[mSeries].Points.AddXY(timestring, mData);

                    chartPointROI.ResetAutoValues();
                }
            }
```

Using this code I am putting the data on the `chart control`. 
The `X-axis` representing Time and `Y-axis` representing Data.

Initailly when I select any item of `listbox` the series starts from left side, but after sometime if I start one more series it will also start from left side but I want to start that from the current time which is representing on X-axis.

And when I stop any `series` after some time if I again start the same `series` I want to some gap in the series so that it can be clearly seen that series is been stopped.

In my case the series always starts from left side. And if I stop any series and start that again It will continue where it stopped.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**

[image]

It is showing that

Comment: `Points.AddXY(timestring, mData);` this look very much as if you add __x-values as strings__. Do not do that if you expect them to have any meaning! If x-axis is datetime do add the values as __datetime__!! Then report back, if the issue persists!

Comment: Thank you Sir this solve my problem to start the chart series from right side although this  doesn't hide the series the check box is unchecked.  It connect the series to the time  when I again start that.

Comment: Well hiding a series is best done by setting `series.Enabled = false`. I see no attempt to hide a series, though..

Comment: series.Enabled = false hide whole series but I want to hide of particular portion

Comment: OK. What exactly do you mean by 'hide'? You can a) make DataPoints invisible by changing their color to Transparent, which will kepp them in place and keep the layout fixed. Or you can b) zoom into a portion. Or you can c) remove DataPoints, either completely or move them to a List<DataPoint>. This will trigger a new layout and be a bit slow, depending on the numbers. As long as the x-values are numeric or dates they will always be reinserted at the right spots..

Comment: How  I can remove the data points

Comment: ?? You are already removing DataPoints, no? If you want to re-add those later you can do a pointList.Add(chartPointROI.Series[mSeries].Points[someindex]); before removing with chartPointROI.Series[mSeries].Points.RemoveAt(someIndex); Just make sure to keep track of the umbers you want to remove. Indices of all points after a removed one will slip to the left, as usual..

Comment: I want to remove for particular time period which is shown in X axis

Comment: Well, you can lop over the points and while(x-value > startperiod && x-value < endperiod) mark for removal. then remove or copy..

Comment: can you provide the code if possible

Comment: Yes, of course. Do note however that removing points from the middle will create gaps. All points will stay at theit correct dates/tines on the x-axis! Thus the line will connect from the last to the first remaining datapoint..!

Comment: yes please provide the code I want that gap between the line

Comment: To make the axis show dates tell the series about it: `yourSeries.XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;` To control the format use `yourChartarea.AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = someFormatString;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of how to remove a few `DataPoints` and also of how to restore them.

Note the flat line in the gap. If you want to 'remove' that line best color the last point transparent; I have added commented code for this.

```
List<DataPoint> marked = new List<DataPoint>();
int markedStartIndex = -1;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // I create a testperiod to remove
    DateTime dt0 = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(2);
    DateTime dt1 = dt0.AddHours(123);
    DateTime dt2 = dt0.AddHours(173);

    // convert to doubles:
    double startPeriod = dt1.ToOADate();
    double endPeriod = dt2.ToOADate();

    // short reference
    Series s = chart1.Series[0];
    // select the points in the period. pick your border conditions!
    marked = s.Points.Cast<DataPoint>()
                     .Where(x => x.XValue > startPeriod && x.XValue < endPeriod)
                     .ToList();

    if (marked.Count < 1) return;

    // remember where we started to remove
    markedStartIndex = s.Points.IndexOf(marked.First()); 
    foreach (DataPoint dp in marked) s.Points.Remove(dp);

    // Optionally 'hide' the gap line
    //if (markedStartIndex > 0) s.Points[markedStartIndex].Color = Color.Transparent;
}
```

The code to bring them back inserts them at the right spot and then clears the points.:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Series s = chart1.Series[0];
    // optionally re-color the gap-line 
    //if (markedStartIndex > 0) s.Points[markedStartIndex].Color = s.Color;

    foreach (DataPoint dp in marked) s.Points.Insert(markedStartIndex++, dp);
    marked.Clear();
}
```

Result with a transparent gap:

[image]

You could also color the gap in red and also store more than one set of points; for this you would have to store the starting points as well as make sure to manage multiple periods when you re-insert them!

As an alternative to actually removing the points you could also choose to simply color them transparent..

Comment: In my code when I replace the value of x in addXY function to datetime it start the series from right but it shows any other value not the datetime on X -axis

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Can you explain in more detail?

Comment: Making  it `yourChartarea.AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "hh:mm:ss"` should be enough, no?